# Ubuntu 14.04 Server - WiFi WPA2 Personal

Tags: wireless, networking, server

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server and cannot get wifi configured correctly to work with WPA2 personal and could use some help.

There was a simple wizard during install where I selected my SSID from a list and entered my passphrase and that worked great.  Now that the install is done I am having trouble configuring wifi.  My Access Point is setup to WPA2 Personal TKIP or AES. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I have been messing around with WPA supplicant ant my /etc/network/interfaces file with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I suggest you set up /etc/network/interfaces something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point. Of course, substitute your details here.

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.1.1
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: This answer did the trick.  I had done this a number of times before and one capital letter off in the SSID caused it not to work.  Been ripping out my hair for days and finally resorted to posting this call for help and it comes down to a simple typo. Your answer did confirm that i was not crazy in my config approach and that affirmation you provided was something I needed in order to look closer.  Thanks for the quick and simply help.  This is exactly why I love the Ubuntu community and why I choose to use the product!  Thank you for the support!

Comment: I added the lines auto wlan0, iface wlan0 inet dhcp, wpa-ssid <your_router>, and wpa-psk <your_wpa_key> after the auto lo section.  My file ends with auto p4p1, iface p4p1 inet dhcp (there by default).  I was able to connect to my wifi.  If I restart, things are fine if network cable is plugged.  If unplugged, the 'Starting configure network device' step in the startup hangs, and takes two rounds of 60 seconds before system continues (message: waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration).  Then I get 'booting system without full network config'. Wifi works, but how do i 'fix' this?

Comment: @VinhNguyen In ifconfig do you have a wlan0 interface? I suspect you'll need to ask your own new question.

Comment: FYI I posted the question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/541247/ubuntu-server-wifi

Comment: you saved me hours of running-in-circles... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've used `ifconfig -a` to see what interfaces my machine has, it had no `wlan0`, but it did have `wlp2s0` so I change the script above to that and now I'm online!

Answer (score 33):

I managed to connect to my WPA2 access point by putting the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Slightly modified from the accepted answer, and using DHCP.

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
```

Then a simple `sudo ifup -v wlan0` and it connected. All good.

Comment: Perfect! On `15.10`, `wlan0` is named `wls1` by default.

Comment: This worked for me aswell

Comment: Here is how to store a hash of the key instead of the key itself: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274095/how-to-encrypt-hide-password-in-etc-network-interfaces-file-on-debian

Comment: It's important to use the name of the WiFi interface of your system! Type `ifconfig -a` or `ip a`: the name of the WiFi interface usually starts with `w`. For example, on my Ubuntu 16.04 server it's called `wlp5s0`. Use this name in `/etc/network/interfaces` instead of `wlan0`.

Comment: I have since found NetworkManager and the commandline nmcli tool useful for doing this.

Comment: Works for me with 16.04.3 using an USB dlink dwl-g122 dongle THX !!!

Comment: Thanks king owe you one! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using either DHCP or a static config (doesn't matter which)--AND assuming your wifi worked during install--make your **/etc/network/interfaces** look something like below (for **wlan0** should match the name of your wifi card listed under **ifconfig -a** e.g. your detected wifi card could be nicknamed **eth1** by the OS for all I know.):

```
 auto lo iface lo inet loopback     
 auto wlan0 iface wlan0 inet dhcp    
 wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

To configure wpa_supplicant use the command (Referenced in the config above)

```
wpa_passphrase "YOUR_SSID" SSID_PASSWORD | sudo tee /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Next, create a new executable script named **iwconfig** (you can name this script anything really, "iwconfig-default-ssid", perhaps?--I just made it short for the example):

```
sudo touch /etc/network/if-up.d/iwconfig && sudo chmod 700
/etc/network/if-up.d/iwconfig && sudo ln -s
/etc/network/if-up.d/iwconfig /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iwconfig
```

Now edit **/etc/network/if-up.d/iwconfig**  and add the SSID you want Ubuntu Server to connect to on startup:

```
#!/bin/sh
iwconfig wlan0 essid "YOUR_DEFAULT_SSID" mode managed
```

Now bring ifdown (if you haven't already), then ifup, and you should be golden now and when you reboot (as long as you're near your SSID.)

---

If you're out in public with your laptop with this config, you'll have to use: **iwlist wlan0 scan**, then **sudo iwconfig essid "PUBLIC_ESSID" mode managed** to connect with anything (and/or make a unique script for each place(s) you visit--just **don't** put any of these scripts under the 'if-up.rc.d' folder. /etc/network/interfaces can also handle location alias, so check the man/forums for help on this.)

Or you can try your luck with the CLI frontend for **wicd** when roaming about town:

> sudo apt-get install wicd-curses

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using Network Manager or Wicd. While Network Manager does have a few GUI dependencies which you might dislike having on a headless server, connecting to wifi is quite simple. For a hotspot setup by my Android phone (called Android AP), I could connect using:

```
nmcli dev wifi connect 'Android AP' password test
```

You might find WICD more useful, as curses-based interface as well (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/wicd-curses.8.html). I haven't used it much, so I am not sure of the syntax for connecting to wifi.

If `/etc/network/interfaces` is your only option, maybe you could show what you have done so far to see how we might fix it.

Comment: nmcli worked as a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

A real good super easy way to set up WiFi on the command line is with **nmtui** but I can't find how to install it.