# Ubuntu server 14.04 can't update internet problem

Tags: wireless, networking, server, mode

I recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu server 14.04. The install was fine.
But after the install the problems begin. To be sure I have al the recent updates I typed `sudo apt-get update`. The result I get is no update only errors. It somehow can't fetch any of the stated links. So I tought maybe the links are wrong but that ain't the problem. I changed the links and it still doesn't work.

So I tought maybe there is a problem with my internet connection (I use WIFI).
So I googled around and found this post: [Ubuntu 14.04 Server - WiFi WPA2 Personal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal). After I tried that the following results:
iwconfig:

```
lo no wireless extensions
wlan0 IEE 802.11ng ESSID:off/any 
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragnebt thr:off
Power Management:on
```

ifconfig:

```
lo all the normal values
```

In `/etc/network/interfaces` I have the following:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.000.15 # (000) is something else
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.000.1 ipconfig from a windows pc gives (so not from the router itself)
wpa-ssid the network name
wpa-psk the network password
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Also ping doesn't give me anything to work with.
If I ping the ip adress I entered in interfaces it will receive the packages.
If I ping google I get `host unknow`

During installation I installed the following packages:

- ubuntu basic server;
- OpenSSH;
- Apache server;
- mail server;
- samba file server

**Added:**
When I do`sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0` all things seems to be normal except for 2 things: on the 1st line: `ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured` and on the last line: `Failed to bring up wlan0`

**Update** After a few reboots iwconfig now returns:

```
lo no wireless extensions
wlan0 IEE 802.11ng ESSID:"my network name"
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.427 GHz Access Point: blabla
Bit rate=54Mb/s Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragnebt thr:off
Power Management:on
and so on
```

So I hope everything is now working

If I need to add more information please let me know.
I hope someone can fix my problem with internet connection. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `iwconfig` is not showing any connection to an access point (?) Is the access point configured for WPA? Are you sure you got the password correct? Did you install wpasupplicant? By the way, is there any reason you are configuring networking manually instead of using network-manager?

Comment: @bain Is there an network-manager for ubuntu server? I tought network-manager was only for the gui. `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0` returns ok on both ssid and wpa

Comment: It is working after a few reboots? Did you change anything? The text you pasted for iwconfig clearly showed `Access Point: Not-Associated`

Comment: @bain Yes it appears to be wokring now. I don't know why but after a few reboots I didn't get an error message on `sudo apt-get update` like I did before. Now there is something wrong with 1 of the links to the packages. But thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please amend your interfaces file to correct:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

The s at the end is crucial. Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

The -v for verbose will produce some messages indicating probable success or errors. Test:

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

By the way, you are behind a router and you have a private IP address. Your 192.168.x.y or 10.0.1.x address gives away nothing personally identifiable, but could help us diagnose your issue.

Comment: I did a reboot and edited some info above. It turns out that I did had nameservers and I had 1 wrong number in my gateway. I chnaged this but I still get `ping: unknown host`

Comment: There is no connection to the wifi AP, so DNS is not the issue.

Comment: Perhaps it is a driver problem. Do you have and eth0 in: ifconfig? Can you ping the router? ping -c3 192.168.xxx.1

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your gateway ,it should be same as of printed on your router. 
If that's not the problem,

1. Comment out static settings
2. Use **dhcp** again
3. Restart with
   **sudo reboot**
4. **ping www.google.com**
5. If works use **ifconfig** to see your correct settings, and use them again in your configuration file.