# Ubuntu Server 14 wireless connection configuration

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, server

Good day.
I have fresh Ubuntu Server 14 installed (with updates).
I already tried this solutions w/o result:

[Setting up wireless (WPA2) on ubuntu server 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521188/setting-up-wireless-wpa2-on-ubuntu-server-14-04)

[Automatically connect to a wireless network using CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412325/automatically-connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-cli)

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Ethernet
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Wireless
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid network_name
wpa-psk network_password
```

So after reboot it doesn't connect to wireless connection automatically.
Only after run command:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

system connect to wireless network.

Can you please tell me how to fix it or where i make mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your *interfaces* file asks both ethernet and wireless to start automatically. If the ethernet cable is detached, obviously it can't.

Moreover, in a server, which usually runs headless, it is preferable to set a static IP address so that you can easily ssh and ftp into it. Therefor, I suggest that your interfaces file be set up like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point. Of course, substitute your details here.

Comment: i don't need static, i need dhcp because i don't know other data and wireless connection often changed. i make update to file: http://take.ms/yzXPs but no lucky — not connected :(

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep wlan`

Comment: i don`t found any way to fix it, so i make next: 1) re-install ubuntu server with connected enternet connection; 2) check do not install update automatically; 3) after ubuntu was installed i add configuration (as i wrote in my first question) to /etc/network/interfaces file; 4) reboot server with disconnected eth0; 5) profit — after reboot server connected to WiFi Router automatically

Comment: I'm glad it's working by whatever means.

Comment: thanks you for help, chili555 :) but it is wired why i was need to re-install OS for correct wlan/eth working. Maybe via installation ubuntu configure ethernet automatically more correctly then later :(