# ubuntu server: wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, server

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 server on my computer that has both a wired network port and a wifi card.  I would like for the server to use the wired network if is not available, and use wifi when it is not available.

The original /etc/network/interfaces look like the following:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet dhcp
```

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal) post and modified my file to be:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <my_ssid>
wpa-psk <my_ssid_password>

# The primary network interface
auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet dhcp
```

When I restart wlan0, I'm able to connect to my wifi, no problem.  If I restart the computer with my network cable plugged in, no problems either as both the wired and wifi connections connect to my network.  However, if I have my wired connection unplugged and reboot, I see the message 'Starting configure network device' at startup.  I then see the message 'waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration' before the system fully boots (so it waits 120+ seconds for the network).  When the computer boots, my wifi connections is connected.

So, I guess things work, but the my headless server takes a long time to fully boot.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there anyway to fix this bootup lag?  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The declarations 'auto p4p1' and 'auto wlan0' ask the system to automatically start *both* interfaces. When you start with the ethernet detached and have asked that the interface start anyway, the system stumbles: "waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration."

It would be more efficient, but certainly not automatic, to leave out the 'auto' declaration:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <my_ssid>
wpa-psk <my_ssid_password>

# The primary network interface
#auto p4p1
iface p4p1 inet dhcp
```

And start either interface manually as needed:

```
sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I reduced sleep time at the three locations in /etc/init/failsafe as described at http://tech.pedersen-live.com/2012/05/disable-waiting-for-network-configuration-messages-on-ubuntu-boot/.

Comment: Old question I know, but I'm curious how to make the setting stick.  I have to do the manual start each time I reboot.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChuckClaunch Please start your own new question and explain in detail what you need. Please include: `cat  /etc/network/interfaces` Please obscure your password.