# I just installed ubuntu server 16.04 xenial in an old machine (small server at home). Wifi was used in installation but now it's gone, why?

Tags: networking, wireless, server

I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 and when asked in installation which lan interface I would like to use as default, I chose my wlan. It worked during installation.

Now that the installation finished and I booted for the first time, wlan is not working. Wasn't this supposed to work out of the box since during installation I marked my wlan to be default, and it worked?

I know someone will just post how to configure the wlan (we have some older posts like [Ubuntu 14.04 Server - WiFi WPA2 Personal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal) that helps with the configuration or [ubuntu server: wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541247/ubuntu-server-wifi)), but that's beside the point, what's the use of asking for a default lan interface when installing if after finishing the installation I need to manually open configuration files and reconfigure my wifi?

`/etc/network/interfaces`

Has only

`source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

Going to `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` (even as root) shows nothing.

And `ifconfig`

`lo Link encap: Local Loopback
inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mas 255.0.0.0`

Weren't these files supposed to have a configuration since I just installed Ubuntu Server?

Comment: please edit your question to post the output of cat /etc/network/interfaces and ifconfig

Comment: @CollDue96 indeed it's just the loopback.

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu server 16.04 i386 to an old Dell Dimension 2400 and had a similar experience. The installer made a successful wifi connection during install but fails after reboot. 

Instead of showing as  'wlan0' the attached USB dongle came up as 'wlxc83a35c69626' during install. Or some similar 'wlx............' string; preceding is what shows now via 'iwconfig' and via 'ls /sys/class/net'. Both of which now also show a second USB dongle I've since plugged in as 'wlx00e04c8191df'.

'/etc/network/interfaces' and 'ifconfig' only show loopback.

Comment: @kevjonesin yep, I had the same problem, not wlan0 but wsomething and just loopback. The manual lan config, actually, is simple/easy to set , but if it works when you installed, it should work out of the box after the installation finishes. I think we'll need to get in touch with someone from Ubuntu or even fill a  bug report.