# WPA2-Personal Wireless issues

Tags: networking, wpa2

I've been having a major struggle getting my machine connected to my personal network at home.

Here is my current setup:
I have a Lenovo5536 running Ubuntu server 14.04. I cannot use Ethernet to connect it to my network so I am used a TPlink772n USB wireless adapter. My network runs WPA2 personal, with the SSID hidden

My issues started from the installation of Ubuntu. It gave me the option between my network interfaces (The onboard ethernet port or the USB adapter) So I selected the USB adapter. My network did not show up as an option so I "Enter ESSID Manually " and after typing in the SSID and the password, no luck. I get an error message saying " Failure of key exchange and association"

At first I figured it was driver issues related to the USB adapter. After some research I determined the drivers were already packed in with Ubuntu.

I then followed this tutorial to manually configure the interface:
[Ubuntu 14.04 Server - WiFi WPA2 Personal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal)
But no luck

My next assumption was ubuntu dose not support this, however I built a test network on an extra linksys router, WPA2 personal, password, But left the SSID open (not hidden) I was able to connect to it from the installation screen.

So my theory is it has something to do with the SSID being hidden. I am very new to Linux, and am basically jumping into the ocean, without knowing how to swim. If someone could pleease explain to me why this is happening ( with as much detail as possible, because I do not know what I am doing) It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the output from ifconfig and iwconfig after you have entered the ESSID manually?