# Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS IP address nonexistent

Tags: 14.04, wireless, webserver

I am a complete beginner when trying to set up a web server. Anyhow, I decided to attempt to set up a Ubuntu server on an old laptop of mine (About two - three years old).

I followed the instructions in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKJ55ebMcOc and everything was working fine.

However, my laptop is run on wifi and not a VM or ethernet port as shown in the video at approximately 15:31.

When I run `ifconfig` command, I only get the "lo - local loopback" results. Thus, I do not have an IP address and without an IP address I think I am unable to do anything. The laptop was able to connect to my router during the installation because it downloaded some files during that time.

I saw this question and answer and attempted it [Ubuntu 14.04 Server - WiFi WPA2 Personal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal)
But for some reason I am unable to get to `etc/network/interfaces/` (says it is not a directory) I can only get to `etc/network`

Any idea as to why I am unable to change directory to `etc/network/interfaces` or how else I can make it work?

Comment: It's not a directory, it's a file - you *get to* the directory `/etc/network/` and then *open* the file `interfaces` in a text editor. Or just open the file using an absolute path e.g. `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*/etc/network* is the directory

*interfaces* is a file, not a directory

You may edit the file with a text editor

```
# nano /etc/network/interfaces
```