# Setting up a static network ip on Ubuntu Server via Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, server

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/464552/148451) and added in the interfaces file these lines:

```
auto wlx...
iface wlx... inet static
address 192.168.2.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <my_router>
wpa-psk <my_wpa_key>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

`ifconfig` outputs my Wifi dongle as `wlx..` instead of `wlan0` (that's why I changed it).

When doing `sudo ifup wlx...` I get:

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring wlx...
```

Why does this appear?

---

The bigger context is described here: [Make Ubuntu Server to connect automatically to WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/q/861287/148451), but it was closed as duplicate.

Comment: I suspect that we will find the answer in: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep wpa` Please run that in the terminal and post the result. If it is more than 6 lines, paste it here and give us the link: `http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: As well, I will suggest corrections to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: @chili555 Actually... after rebooting the machine, it just worked with the same config... It got a static ip on the network (`192.168.2.150`) I can use and connect to it.