# Ubuntu Server doesn't accept ssh connections unless restarting the Wifi connection

Tags: networking, wireless, server, ssh

I have configured a Wifi connection on my Ubuntu Server powered machine, following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/464552/148451).

I also configured ssh so I can connect from other machines to this machine when it's running. Everything works fine, *but*, every time I start the machine, first I have to login, and do:

```
ifdown ...
ifup ...
```

The internet connection does work before running these two commands, but accepting SSH connections doesn't work.

After restarting the Wifi connection, I can `ssh` from my other machines.

How to solve this problem? Why does this appear at all?

Comment: what relevant logs are in the `/var/log`?

Comment: @Jakuje Um, there are a lot of files there. Is there anything specific we would be interested in?

Comment: Maybe `sshd` is starting before the WiFi connection is established, and thus only listens on wired connection (if any).

Comment: @ridgy You may be right. I remember this used to work when it was using a wired connection. Now I'm using a wifi dongle.

Comment: You should see the status of `ssh` when running `systemctl status sshd`. The logs related to `sshd` should be in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: Does your wifi automatically connect to any access points? I'm wondering if it connects to a network and then gets routes from a dhcp server and then suddenly has problems connecting because of that. What is the topology of your network?

Comment: @KyleH It just connects to the router, getting a static ip on the network (`192.168.2.150`).