# Connect to WiFi using iwconfig and BSSID

Tags: wireless

I am running ubuntu 14.04 server and I tried to use the below command to connect to WiFi using BSSID, it is not throwing me any error but still failed to connect to that AP. Do I need to run another command to make the connection effective?

`iwconfig wlan0 ap bssid`

Comment: There is no error, its as if the set has taken place but we need to do something else to make it effective.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal/464552#464552

Comment: Thanks for the share, but i want to specifically connect to a BSSID.

Comment: Does the BSSID use encryption? I know of no way for `iwconfig` to specify it. Then, you need to ask for a connection. Does the BSSID serve DHCP?

Comment: BSSID use encryption and yes it serves DHCP. Currently i have decided to use nmcli which uses Network Manager.