# Ubuntu server 16.04 no wireless internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless, server, internet

I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 server and can't get WIFI to work. My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid lomboboo
wpa-psk password
```

I also tried this setup as it was suggested in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal/464552#464552):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid lomboboo
wpa-psk password
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

But none of them work.

Also this is info from **ifconfig** [image]

**P.S.** Don't know if it matters - Ubuntu 16.04 server is running on Raspberry Pi 3.

**EDITED** 
`sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0` output:
[image]

`ping -c3 8.8.8.8` output:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of: `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0` and also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

Comment: @chili555 just updated the question

Comment: Is this a virtual machine? I don't understand `50-cloud-init.cfg`.  Sorry.

Comment: @chili555 actually no, it is not. I've installed Ubuntu from this image ``ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz`` on my Raspberry Pi 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that you have set `wpa-psk` in /etc/network/interfaces to the passphrase for your wireless network. That will not work.

Let's say the SSID for my router is `MYROUTER`, and I set the WPA/WPA2 passphrase on my router to `MySecretPassphrase`. At first glance, you would think that /etc/network/interfaces should look like this:

```
wpa-ssid MYROUTER
wpa-psk MySecretPassphrase
```

Wrong. I made this mistake a few months ago, and it took me a while to figure why it was not working. In short, `wpa-psk` should be set to the 256-bit pre-shared key for this SSID. Do not set `wpa-psk` to the passphrase.

How do you that? By using the `wpa_passphrase` command (if it isn't installed, you can install it with `sudo apt install wpasupplicant`). From the man page:

> wpa_passphrase  pre-computes  PSK  entries  for  network 
>   configuration blocks of a wpa_supplicant.conf file. An ASCII
>   passphrase and SSID  are used to generate a 256-bit PSK.

Let's give it a try:

```
~$ wpa_passphrase MYROUTER MySecretPassphrase
```

Output:

```
network={
    ssid="MYROUTER"
    #psk="MySecretPassphrase"
    psk=93763b13c803b7269956cb9bf584c75eb0fd0e99c51ecf49598a4016a29aa3f1
}
```

Assuming the wireless adapter is labeled wlan0, the /etc/network/interfaces file for the example above should look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid MYROUTER
wpa-psk 93763b13c803b7269956cb9bf584c75eb0fd0e99c51ecf49598a4016a29aa3f1
```

Instead of typing this long string or using copy/paste, you can do this to append the relevant lines to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
~$ wpa_passphrase MYROUTER MySecretPassphrase | grep -vE "{|#|}" | tr -d '\t' | sudo tee -a /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then edit /etc/network/interfaces to make sure everything looks right.

Finally, either reboot or restart the networking service:

```
~$ sudo service networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
auto an_usb_interface
iface an_usb_interface inet dhcp

wpa-ssid MYROUTER
wpa-psk MySecretPassphrase
```

was enough.

I answered this because the answer at this question is saying that this is wrong and to use the 256-bit pre-shared key for this SSID, but this is working (and cannot comment there yet; wpasupplicant is used at some point by `/etc/init.d/networking start`).

Comment: This answer is very very unclear.