# Wireless Network Manager command line ncurses GUI

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ncurses

Is there any software that can manage wireless network connection using ncurses?

So I just installed Ubuntu Server 17.04, trying to connect via wireless, but `iwconfig` not installed, so I install [wireless-tools](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/zesty/main/base/wireless-tools), copy the .deb via usb drive, then run `dpkg -i`, but apparently it requires [libiw30](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/libiw30/download), download and copy again via usb drive, then installed successfully.

so now I can connect to internet without encryption through my android phone by running

```
ifconfig wlp4s0 down
dhclient -r wlp4s0 
iwconfig wlp4s0 essid android_tether
iwconfig wlp4s0 mode Managed
ifconfig wlp4s0 up
dhclient wlp4s0
```

Now I have internet connection, but still I cannot connect to my office's WPA2 Access Point (which is 10x faster: n/ac). Is there any ncurses UI way to connect to WPA2?

Because I've tried the `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
   #wpa-ssid office_net
   #wpa-psk office_net_password
   wireless-essid office_net
   wireless-psk office_net_password
```

It always make the the booting process stuck (timeout), not getting the ip address, I must reboot each time to recovery mode to change it.

Comment: WICD has a curses-based TUI

Comment: I believe it is `wpa-ssid` and also `wpa-psk`. Please amend your interfaces file and try again. Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal/464552#464552

Comment: Yes I've tried those but ain't got the ip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `nmtui`. It's provided by Network Manager installation along with `nmcli`, and  seems to have been available for quite a few years: https://github.com/heftig/NetworkManager/tree/master/tui

Comment: Please spread the word about nmtui, i've searched whole internet for alternatives and i've found only your post mentioning this. The only alternative which really works well