# Setting up wireless on Ubuntu Server 17.04

Tags: wireless, server, 17.04

I've looked everywhere but can't find how to activate wireless networking. WLAN0 appears not to be working or activated.

Thanks

PS:Too Short?

Edit: Already tried that answer. Has not worked.
The output of `ifconfig` is:

```
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.16  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 fe80::223:5aff:fed9:7a72  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:23:5a:d9:7a:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 118  bytes 9321 (9.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 78  bytes 8089 (8.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 3  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 713  bytes 56816 (56.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 713  bytes 56816 (56.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.150  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    ether 00:24:2c:67:8a:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

EDIT 2
I'm kinda an ubuntu noob. Thanks 4 ur patience. :)
Output of `sudo lshw -C network` is

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:24:2c:67:8a:a0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=b43 driverversion=4.10.0-19-generic firmware=666.2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:f0300000-f0303fff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AR8132 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: enp5s0
   version: c0
   serial: 00:23:5a:d9:7a:72
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI ip=10.0.0.16 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:27 memory:f0200000-f023ffff ioport:a000(size=128)
```

And `iwconfig` is

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
```

Edit 3:
`A start job is running for raise network interfaces (-----/5m 34s)`or something like that. Mean anything to you?

Comment: Is it a PCI or USB wireless?

Comment: Please execute the command `ifconfig` and edit your question to include the output

Comment: Did you look here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal/464552#464552

Comment: Can you also add the outputs of `sudo lshw -C network` and `iwconfig` to your question?

Comment: Again, what *exactly* did you try, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Were there error messages? Did you struggle to find the appropriate user interface controls for your aims? I can't make anything out of what you told us so far. "I looked everywhere" isn't helpful – if that were literally true there would be no point in looking further.