# Should wifi work after Server install?

Tags: networking, server

I just installed Ubuntu Server.  When installing, it asked for the SSID and password.  I provided both.  Following the install and reboot, I appear to not have network connectivity.  A wget to http://www.yahoo.com fails.  Is there something needed to get wifi networking running each boot, or should it have started - and I have a problem?

Comment: The SSID/password information is not saved with the install process. You should be able to simply enter the information once more on the finished install, and it will then save it between reboots.

Comment: I used the command "ip link show" to get a list of NICs.  I found one called "wlx0024a5aac476".  All the examples I see show a name like "wlan0".  Does mine look right?

Comment: It is correct if yours is a USB wireless. Is it?

Comment: @GTrawo Servers do not typically run Network Manager so there is no simple way to "simply enter the information." Usually, it is necessary to edit a system file.

Comment: @chili555 You are absolutely right. I totally skipped over the 'server' part.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464507/ubuntu-14-04-server-wifi-wpa2-personal/464552#464552 Of course, substitute wlx0024a5aac476 for wlan0 throughout. Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Yes, its a USB dongle.